# RequestListener in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working with symfony2.3.
I create RequestListener and write when user login and go to home action then 
earned some Rewards points.This is working.
But How I can do this points earned only when user come home action first time.If user come home action more than one time then not update Rewards Points ?

RequestListner.php

```
<?php

namespace XXX\ABCBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Thinkdigit\UserBundle\Entity\User;


class RequestListener
{
/**
 * @var \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface
 */
protected $securityContext;

protected $em;

/**
 * Container
 *
 * @var ContainerInterface
 */
protected $container;

/**
 * Listener constructor
 *
 * @param ContainerInterface $container
 */
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, SecurityContextInterface $securityContext, EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->container = $container;
    $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    $this->em = $em;
}

/**
 * kernel.request Event
 *
 * @param GetResponseEvent $event
 */
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $request  = $event->getRequest();
    $controller = $request->get('_controller');


$home     = array('XXX\ABCBundle\Controller\PageHomeController::indexAction', 'XXX\ABCBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::confirmedAction');


  //print_r($controller);die;
    if ( $this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'))
    {
        if(in_array($controller,$home)){
            $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
            //print_r($user->getRewardPoints());
            $point = '5';
            $rewrdPoint = $user->getRewardPoints() + $point;
            $user->setRewardPoints($rewrdPoint);
            $this->em->persist($user);
            $this->em->flush($user);
            //die;
        }
    }
    // Here you can intercept all HTTP requests, and through $container get access to user information
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a symfony related; The simplest way is to store something in session an check for it;

like, on opening home page for logged in user, just set him a session var, and check for session var before handle request listener;

```
if($controller == $home && $this->container->get('session')->get('reward_was_payed', 0) != 1){
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    //print_r($user->getRewardPoints());
    $point = '5';
    $rewrdPoint = $user->getRewardPoints() + $point;
    $user->setRewardPoints($rewrdPoint);
    $this->em->persist($user);
    $this->em->flush($user);

    $this->container->set('reward_was_payed', 1);
}

;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, Can you see my question again I was changed . $home is array .

Comment: so just change if($controller == $home && $this->container->get('session')->get('reward_was_payed', 0) != 1){
 to if(in_array($controller,$home) && $this->container->get('session')->get('reward_was_payed', 0) != 1){

Comment: check the debug, it this value is setted

Comment: If value in session is set, then it is impossible, the get('session')->get('reward_was_payed', 0) must return 1; and in this case, it couldn't execute this part of code